# How to prime cache on all location of a cdn

Tags: wordpress, performance, cache, cdn

I have just started using MaxCDN to serve static resources faster (images, js and css mostly).

It works great, as long as the data is cached on the cdn's location that is close to where I live. But testing with pingdom from various location has given me pretty awful results - up to 12 seconds to load a 77Kb css file ! 
This is because if the site has not been accessed yet from that particular location, the cdn server has to fetch resource from my server and cache it before serving it to my visior - yet I don't understand how it can take so long....

So it may be a dumb question but how do I make sure that all my resources are cached from all locations ? Is there a way to prime cache the same way as I prime cache on my server by making requests at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1):

The free-est way to do this is to use those public website speedtest tool with presence at multiple regions. uptrends and keycdn both offer test locations from over all over the world.

By initiating tests from all the regions should prime your CDN.